# How can I use initialized instance objects from another class in C#?

Tags: c#, class, object, initialization

I have Class1 for constants. In Class2, two instances of Class1 are created and initialized by user. How can I use these instances (which their values were sat by user) in Program?

I have searched the questions, but do not find any related post.

Class1 which contains the variables:

```
namespace project1
{
    public class Class1
    {
        public int var1;
        public double var2;
    }
}
```

Class2 in which two instances of Class1 are initialized:

```
namespace project2
{
    public class Class2
    {
        public void Method2_1()
        {
            var constants1 = new project1.Class1
            {
                var1 = 1,
                var2 = 1.1
            };
        }
        public void Method2_2()
        {
            var constants2 = new project1.Class1
            {
                var1 = 2,
                var2 = 2.2
            };
        }
    }
}
```

Program in which I want to use the two initialized instances of Class1:

```
namespace Project3
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //How can I use two instances "constants1" and "constants2" of Class1, separately, which are initialized in Class2 !?
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks for your time.

Comment: `constants1` and `constants2` effectively cease to exist at the end of the `Method2_1()` and `Method2_2()` methods.

Comment: Yes, your are right, how can I change the code so that I can use the values in Program?

Comment: Maybe try to return values from your methods? (change this public void Method2_x to public Class1 Method2_x(){return new Class1(){ var1 = xxx, var2 = xxx};}

Comment: Thanks @taktak, I will try your method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one solution :

```
public class Class1
{
    public int var1;
    public double var2;

    public override string ToString(){
        return "var1 : " + var1 + " var2 : " + var2;
    }
}
public class Class2
{
    public Class1 Method2_1()
    {
        return new Class1
        {
            var1 = 1,
            var2 = 1.1
        };
    }
    public Class1 Method2_2()
    {
        return new Class1
        {
            var1 = 2,
            var2 = 2.2
        };
    }
}
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //Your code goes here
        var c1 = new Class2();
        var testM1 = c1.Method2_1();
        var testM2 = c1.Method2_2();
        Console.WriteLine("testM1 : " + testM1.ToString());
        Console.WriteLine("testM2 : " + testM2.ToString());

    }
}
```

You have to know that calling object from another project isn't a real issue. You just have to include it to your using.

Comment: Your welcome. You can keep training yourself by learning how to return a type within a method, this would be very useful for you